# Solution to part 1 of Day 7 Advent of Code in Scala

Tags: parsing, regex, scala, bitwise

Does someone want to review my solution to part 1 of Day 7 Advent of Code in Scala?
The assignment is here: http://adventofcode.com/day/7
Without repeating the whole text, in short:

Given a text file of the following form (simplified):

```
x AND y -> a
x -> 1
y -> 0
```

calculate the value of a. [Here](https://gist.github.com/borkdude/8d1dc6d66544aeca3fbf) is an example of a full input file.

My solution:

```
import scala.io.Source

object Day7 {

  sealed trait Expr

  case class Variable(name: String) extends Expr

  case class Const(value: Int) extends Expr

  case class Not(expr: Expr) extends Expr

  case class And(left: Expr, right: Expr) extends Expr

  case class Or(left: Expr, right: Expr) extends Expr

  case class LShift(expr: Expr, by: Int) extends Expr

  case class RShift(expr: Expr, by: Int) extends Expr

  case class Assignment(v: Variable, expr: Expr) extends Expr

  case object Command {
    def parse(s: String): Assignment = {
      val assignmentRegex = """(.+) -> (.+)""".r
      def innerParse(s: String): Expr = {
        val rShiftRegex = """(\w+) RSHIFT (\d+)""".r
        val lShiftRegex = """(\w+) LSHIFT (\d+)""".r
        val orRegex = """(\w+) OR (\w+)""".r
        val andRegex = """(\w+) AND (\w+)""".r
        val notRegex = """NOT (\w+)""".r
        val constRegex = """(\d+)""".r
        val varRegex = """(\w+)""".r

        s match {
          case rShiftRegex(l, n) =>
            RShift(innerParse(l), n.toInt)
          case lShiftRegex(l, n) =>
            LShift(innerParse(l), n.toInt)
          case orRegex(l, r) =>
            Or(innerParse(l), innerParse(r))
          case andRegex(l, r) =>
            And(innerParse(l), innerParse(r))
          case notRegex(e) =>
            Not(innerParse(e))
          case constRegex(n) =>
            Const(n.toInt)
          case varRegex(n) =>
            Variable(n)
        }
      }
      s match {
        case assignmentRegex(l, r) => Assignment(Variable(r), innerParse(l))
        case _ => throw new Exception(s"Unrecognized command: $s")
      }
    }
  }

  class Environment(mappings: Map[String, Expr]) {

    val cache = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Expr, Int]()

    private def eval(e: Expr): Int = {
      cache.get(e) match {
        case Some(i) => i
        case None => {
          val result = e match {
            case Variable(name) => {
              println(s"evaluating $name")
              eval(mappings(name))
            }
            case Const(value) => value
            case Not(expr) => ~eval(expr)
            case And(l, r) => eval(l) & eval(r)
            case Or(l, r) => eval(l) | eval(r)
            case LShift(expr, n) => eval(expr) << n
            case RShift(expr, n) => eval(expr) >> n
          }
          cache += (e -> result)
          result
        }
      }
    }

    def call(name: String): Int = {
      eval(mappings(name))
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val lines = Source.fromFile("input-day7.txt").getLines()
    val x = lines.map(Command.parse).map((a) => a match {
      case Assignment(Variable(v), e) => (v -> e)
    })
    val m = x.toMap
    println(new Environment(m).call("a"))

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that your general approach is solid. One small change I noticed you could make would be to move the `Regex` declarations outside of the functions `parse` and `innerParse`. The reason for doing this is that it is expensive to compile the `Regexs` with every call to these functions. By moving them out we only construct them once. This is supported by the Scala Regex documentation which can be read [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex).

```
case object Command {
  val assignmentRegex = """(.+) -> (.+)""".r
  val rShiftRegex     = """(\w+) RSHIFT (\d+)""".r
  val lShiftRegex     = """(\w+) LSHIFT (\d+)""".r
  val constRegex      = """(\d+)""".r
  val varRegex        = """(\w+)""".r
  val notRegex        = """NOT (\w+)""".r
  val andRegex        = """(\w+) AND (\w+)""".r
  val orRegex         = """(\w+) OR (\w+)""".r

  def parse(s: String): Assignment = {
    def innerParse(s: String): Expr = {
      // ...
    }
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought the Scala compiler would maybe optimize this, like in Clojure, where regex literals are only evaluated once during the reader/compile phase.